# One hot encoding and correlation plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding, dummy-variable

I have a data set full of object types. I want to be able to create a correlation plot of this data frame. When I tried to use plt.corr I get a division by zero error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-b3ab1a4234e7> in <module>()
----> 1 plt.matshow(df1.corr())
      2 plt.show()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in matshow(A, fignum, **kw)
   2419     else:
   2420         # Extract actual aspect ratio of array and make appropriately sized figure
-> 2421         fig = figure(fignum, figsize=figaspect(A))
   2422         ax  = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.09, 0.775, 0.775])
   2423 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in figaspect(arg)
   2474     if isarray:
   2475         nr, nc = arg.shape[:2]
-> 2476         arr_ratio = nr / nc
   2477     else:
   2478         arr_ratio = arg

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

I have done my research and I ran into utilizing dummies. I tried to use

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(currentDataFrame)
plt.matshow(dummies.corr())
plt.show()
```

But it is not showing an appropriate correlation plot with all the columns I had. I had printed the dummies and it did transform my data frame into 1s and 0s.

Comment: Please post your error as text, not an image.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that

Comment: please give example of your datasets. It's hard to help without knowing what your data looks like